# cross reference equation caption number in word 2013 issue

Tags: ms-word, equation, caption

I am trying to use the caption function for my equations however I am having some problems. 
I used the 'exclude label from caption option' and the header number option. I copied the caption within parenthesis like this (1.1), however when I use the cross reference function to cite 'only label and number' it is displayed as such
Eq. (1.1
I do not want the any parenthesis. I am looking for Eq. 1.1

I originally used the SEQ function and book mark to number the equations, however I don't know how to add the chapter number to them, hence why I'm changing them to caption.

Could you help me with this?
Many Thanks

Comment: I can achieve this using bookmarks and caption function combined now, however does anyone have a less 'annoying' way of doing it?

Comment: The "header number option" adds a StyleRef field to the SEQ field. I think that's what you're looking for?

Comment: That's great, it works for my chapters.
I have added a new Heading 1 style for my appendices which are:
Appendix A, Appendix B...
However adding the same code to the SEQ field just follows the previous chapter number rather than A.1, A.2

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Not enough information - I have no idea how your field codes look or how you "added a new Heading 1 style".  Generally, however, one uses a higher built-in Heading style number (6, for example), matching its formatting to Heading 1. Then modify the TOC to also use this style at the first TOC level.